# the xampp-control.exe that this shortcut refers to has been changed

Tags: apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP server from past few months without any problems but today suddenly when I tried to open XAMPP  control panel it says the XAMPP -control.exe that this shortcut refers to has been changed shortcut will not work anymore. I tried to uninstall and installed again it works fine but again after a few minutes it disconnects. I tried these process for 3 times but the output is same. I am not able to run apache or MySQL.
What could be the cause how to fix this
[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnXNJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with after installing antivirus,
Now I did uninstalled antivirus and again install xampp. Then it will be work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

1: Right-click on the xampp icon and go ti file location(or xampp folder).

2: Find and delete the following files

xampp-control.ini and  - xampp-control.log

Restart xampp

Answer (score 0):

I have Avast antivirus, and I discovered it removed it and put it in quarantine.
You can either have the AV restore it and add an exception or add the whole XAMPP folder as an exception that the AV should not scan it